# Where is the JTree definition for eclipse's Project Explorer?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The JTree implementation / Renderer used in eclipse (see the navigation pane on the left side) is extremely good.  I've checked out the eclipse source code and am looking through it, but can't seem to find the reference to the JTree used.

Does anyone know which package contains the definition of this pane?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is based on SWT, not Swing. Google "SWT Tree", for example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTreeWithMulticolumns.htm